# Will upgrading my car disqualify it for championships?

Tags: forza-horizon-2

In other Forza games, especially motorsport, Upgrading your car to a different class will disqualify it from certain championships. It seems in Horizon 2 that cars themselves are part of the championship (R35 GTR belongs in supercar championship).

Will it stay as a supercar as I upgrade? Will opponents match my upgrades or will I race against class As as an S2? Haven't tested this myself as money is a little tight and upgrades can be costly.

Comment: From what I have seen I am almost positive that your opponents will match upgrade classes with their car automatically, but I think you have to be in the same genre car (cant have a truck be in a supercar championship) to be eligible for the championship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Upgrades and downgrades will not affect your placement in the championship. Opponent Drivatars will always match your class level plus or minus around 10. Even when you enter certain races, Ben (the event coordinator) makes sure and says "pick what you want, I'll make sure your opponents drive similar cars"

Comment: The only exception to this rule I have found is if you pick the absolute lowest PI car available in the Championship you are racing, sometimes the game will decide that because it can't get any other car that low it will pick cars with potentially much higher PI than you, putting you at a disadvantage.